# import JPlayer in React component (with webpack build process)

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, webpack, jplayer

How do I access the `jPlayer` object within my React component? There are many places I may be doing something wrong, so bear with...

I am developing a Redux/React web application. Starting with the scaffolding provided by the Yeoman generator, [generator-redux](https://github.com/banderson/generator-redux), I have the skeleton of my app in place. This is my first encounter with `webpack`, having used grunt/gulp/bower in the past (though never set those up from scratch, either).

I ran `npm install jquery jplayer --save` so now my `package.json` has

```
"dependencies":{ ...   
   "jplayer": "^2.9.2",
   "jquery": "^2.1.4",
...}
```

and  the jplayer module is in the `node_modules` directory of my project: so far so good. But the jPlayer docs don't make the import process terribly clear, and I'm not sufficiently familiar with the whole node/webpack/babel/etc. ecosystem to be very sure of myself.

My plan is to create a React component called `Player` which will live in a file called `Player.js` in the `js/components` directory. How do I import the jplayer object in this scheme? I'm doing `import { jPlayer} from 'jplayer'` at the head of my `Player.js` which does not seem like it is doing what I want it to be doing, but I'm honestly a bit at a loss of how to check properly. There is no `jPlayer` defined in `this` or the top level in the console...

My imports look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as PlayerActions from '../actions/PlayerActions';
import styles from '../../css/app.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
// import {jPlayer} from 'jplayer/dist/jplayer/jquery.jplayer';
import 'jplayer';
```

For debugging, I also added this to the `Player` class in `Player.js`

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log("Regulators, mount up");
  console.log($('#jquery_jplayer_1'));
  console.log($.jPlayer);
  console.log(jPlayer)
}
```

which gives this output in the Chrome console:

```
Regulators, mount up
[div#jquery_jplayer_1, context: document, selector: "#jquery_jplayer_1"]
undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jPlayer is not defined
```

At this point, I would expect that `$.jPlayer` to be `<jPlayer object>` or some such. I want to call `$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer(...)` at this point, as per the docs for jPlayer.

I know I'm kind of stumbling about blindly here, with a partial knowledge of many components combining into a lot of confusion! Any guidance, and in particular a high-level view of these pieces and their interactions would be most welcome!

In case it's relevant, here's the webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var devFlagPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'false'))
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './js/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/static/',
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    devFlagPlugin,
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?module!cssnext-loader') }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: It looks like `jPlayer` is a jQuery plugin, so it doesn't export an object, it appends itself to the `$` namespace. Test `console.log($.jPlayer)`.

Comment: also you don't import by path, just by name, for npm modules. `import 'jplayer'`

Comment: You are getting that error because you are trying to log a variable you never declared; it has nothing to do with the import.

Comment: yet more. You are of course correct, but `jPlayer` remains undefined on the `$` object, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94248/discussion-between-ben-and-mathletics).

Comment: perhaps you want jPlayer to be an external?  http://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Comment: I created an npm package for react-jPlayer if anyone is interested: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jplayer